# Guest OS provide internet access to another Guest through Host-Only adapter

Tags: networking, routing, virtual-machines

I have a set-up like this:

```
           Ubuntu (Host OS)

OpenWRT(Guest OS) | Damn Small Linux(Guest OS)
```

OpenWRT is connected to Ubuntu through two interfaces, `eth0` via NAT (for internet) and `eth1` via Host-only adapter.

Damn Small Linux has one network adapter, the Host-only adapter which OpenWRT uses.

I would like Damn Small Linux to be able to access the internet through OpenWRT through the Host-only adapter.

Here is a crude drawing I did to try an illustrate the situation:

[image: crude drawing]

Is what I am trying to do possible? Can anybody run through a high level description of what is needed to make this work? I.e OpenWRT acts as a dhcp server for the Host-Only Adapter interface etc..

The idea is this, I am trying to emulate OpenWRT being a physical router connected to the internet on one interface (`eth0`) and providing internet on another (`eth1` / the host-only adapter)

I would appreciate any thoughts or comments on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should work fine.

Some thoughts:

- `eth0` on Damn Small Linux VM must be a attached to the same Host-only network as `eth1` on OpenWRT. Use the IP from `eth1` on OpenWRT as your default Gateway.
- I would use a bridged config for `eth0` on OpenWRT rather than NAT. Assign it a unique IP on your host's network. This will prevent some complications and will also help emulate a physical router better.
- **Be sure to set up any necessary firewall rules or policies in OpenWRT**. Also make sure your default outbound route is set correctly.  If you're using bridged config your next hop is the Gateway for your host network - so all outbound traffic should be routed there.

Specifics:

OpenWRT:

- `eth0` (emulated WAN)

  - IP: unique IP from host network
  - Subnet Mask: same as SM from host network
  - Gateway: Same as GW from host network
- `eth1` (emulated LAN [host-only])

  - IP: unique IP from host-only network
  - Subnet Mask: depends on the host-only network, usually /24
  - Gateway: none (it's a router!)

Damn Small Linux:

- `eth0` (emulated LAN [host-only])

  - IP: unique IP from host-only network
  - Subnet Mask: depends on the host-only network, usually /24
  - Gateway: LAN IP of OpenWRT

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it should be possible if you enable promiscuous mode on your host only network.

Where does Ubuntu fit into this whole picture ? It looks like, as far as the Ubuntu VM is concerned it's connected to just another port on the Host Only virtual switch.

Are you using VMware ? VBox? I believe you should be able to enable promiscuous mode on the Host only virtual switch.